# Custom function which creates loess regression dataset

Tags: r

I have a way of creating a loess regression dataset however I need to perform it multiple times (30+) and was wondering how I could either carry it out in a streamlined fashion or create a function to speed it up?

Current Approach:

```
model           <- loess(mpg ~ wt, data=mtcars)
xrange          <- range(mtcars$wt)
xseq            <- seq(from=xrange[1], to=xrange[2], length=100)
pred            <- predict(model, newdata = data.frame(wt = xseq), se=TRUE)
y               <- pred$fit
loess.DF_mtcars <- data.frame(x = xseq, y=y)
```

Thanks

Comment: What changes in the 30+ times you need to run the process?

Comment: The dataset name, `mtcars`, and the, `mpg`, variable will change. `wt` will never change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider generalizing your process in a function to receive needed patterns. Then, combine your 30+ parameters in a list to call your function via `Map` (non-simplified wrapper to `mapply`) to pass parameters elementwise or in parallel. Final output will be list of predicted loess data sets. Even use `setNames` to render output a named list.

```
proc_loess <- function(df, y_col, x_col="wt", range_col="wt") {

    formula  <- as.formula(paste(y_col, "~", x_col))
    model    <- loess(formula, data=df)
    xrange   <- range(df[[range_col]])
    xseq     <- seq(from=xrange[1], to=xrange[2], length=100)
    pred     <- predict(model, newdata = setNames(data.frame(xseq), range_col), se=TRUE)
    y        <- pred$fit
    loess_df <- data.frame(x = xseq, y=y)

    return(loess_df)
}

# SINGLE RUN (REPRODUCES CURRENT APPROACH)
output_df <- proc_loess(mtcars, "mpg", "wt")

identical(loess.DF_mtcars, output_df)
# [1] TRUE

# MULTIPLE RUN
param_list <- list(df = list(mtcars, mtcars, mtcars),
                   y_col = c("mpg", "hp", "drat"))

pred_loess_df_list <- setNames(Map(proc_loess, param_list$df, param_list$y_col),
                               paste0(param_list$y_col, "_wt"))

# EQUIVALENT CALL
# pred_loess_df_list <- setNames(mapply(proc_loess, param_list$df, param_list$y_col, 
#                                       SIMPLIFY=FALSE),
#                                paste0(param_list$y_col, "_wt"))
```

**Output**

```
head(pred_loess_df_list$mpg_wt)
#          x        y
# 1 1.513000 32.08897
# 2 1.552505 31.76931
# 3 1.592010 31.44638
# 4 1.631515 31.12021
# 5 1.671020 30.79088
# 6 1.710525 30.45842

head(pred_loess_df_list$hp_wt)
#          x        y
# 1 1.513000 79.75120
# 2 1.552505 78.80862
# 3 1.592010 78.02067
# 4 1.631515 77.38788
# 5 1.671020 76.91076
# 6 1.710525 76.58985

head(pred_loess_df_list$drat_wt)
#          x        y
# 1 1.513000 4.312689
# 2 1.552505 4.301782
# 3 1.592010 4.290559
# 4 1.631515 4.279011
# 5 1.671020 4.267129
# 6 1.710525 4.254907
```

---

By the way, the generalized method can apply to other datasets, even swapping out default parameters, *x_col* and *range_col*:

```
param_list <- list(df = list(airquality, ChickWeight, trees),
                   y_col = c("Ozone", "weight", "Girth"),
                   x_col = c("Temp",  "Time", "Volume"),
                   range_col = c("Temp", "Time", "Volume"))

pred_loess_df_list <- setNames(Map(proc_loess, param_list$df, 
                                               param_list$y_col, 
                                               param_list$x_col, 
                                               param_list$range_col),
                               paste0(param_list$y_col, "_", param_list$x_col))
```

**Output**

```
lapply(pred_loess_df_list, head)

# $Ozone_Temp
#          x        y
# 1 56.00000       NA
# 2 56.41414       NA
# 3 56.82828       NA
# 4 57.24242 13.61121
# 5 57.65657 13.69326
# 6 58.07071 13.78077

# $weight_Time
#           x        y
# 1 0.0000000 40.58382
# 2 0.2121212 41.42607
# 3 0.4242424 42.29396
# 4 0.6363636 43.18767
# 5 0.8484848 44.10740
# 6 1.0606061 45.05333

# $Girth_Volume
#          x        y
# 1 10.20000 8.631617
# 2 10.87475 8.838347
# 3 11.54949 9.042601
# 4 12.22424 9.244480
# 5 12.89899 9.444084
# 6 13.57374 9.641514
```

[Rextester Demo](https://rextester.com/OGTHK75896)